# Select Box default value is not showing with [(ngModel)] Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I am using below snippet in my code. If I am applying variable binding "[(ngModel)]" then my default option i.e. "Title*" is not visible. If i remove it then it behave normally and star showing 1st option by default selected.

```
 <select name="title" id="title"title="Please select title" [(ngModel)]="title">
                <option value="title" selected>Title*</option>
                <option value="MD">MD</option>
                <option value="RN">RN</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: my bad!!! I am using formbuilder and i forgot to add <formControlName="title"> in HTML. Now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: @Chellappan - my defualt option was not coming as selected and while it was rendering in DOM, It was showing blank in place of default selection. Hope i am able to clear my point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

property/ngmodel `title` need to be set in your component's class to the `title` element that you want to be pre-selected from `titles` list.
Eg:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Selection</h1>
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="title" >
  <option *ngFor="let titl of titles" [ngValue]="titl.name">{{titl.name}}</option>
</select>
{{title}}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  title:string;
  titles:Array<Object> = [
      {name: "Title*"},
      {name: "MD"},
      {name: "RN"},
      {name: "Mr"},
      {name: "Ms"}
  ];
constructor() {
    //Old Code
   // this.title = this.titles[0]name;

  //New Code
  this.title = this.titles[0]['name'];
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfyuif)

Comment: @AmbujKhanna If the answer was helpful please mark it as correct!

Comment: there is an error in your code. ".name" should be write like "['name']"

Answer (score 7):

You don't even need to use the `selected` attribute.

Angular does everything for you, the only thing you have to understand is that always the option is selected that has the same value that the primitive has, to which it is bound in the component. Hence the name *data-binding*.

So if you have let's say a

```
<select [(ngModel)]="foo" ...
```

and in the *.ts* file the component property `foo` has the value `undefined`, then if you add the option

```
<option [ngValue]="undefined" ...
```

it gets selected by default. If you want, you can also add `disabled="disabled"` so it acts like a placeholder.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks. Feels like now understood the concept to the point. :) Also, instead of ```disabled="disabled"``` , we can directly write ```disabled``` , works as a placeholder as well

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

Give the condition in selected on which scenario the value

" **Title**" should get selected

```
 <select name="title" id="title" #title="ngModel" title="Please select title" [(ngModel)]="title">
            <option [selected]="your condition" [value]="title">Title*</option>
            <option value="MD">MD</option>
            <option value="RN">RN</option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
 </select>


or try the below code

 <select name="title" id="title" #title="ngModel" title="Please select title" [(ngModel)]="title">
        <option [selected]="true" [ngValue]="title">Title*</option>
        <option value="MD">MD</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works, for me. The same scenario is happen in my project. I added some condition for Selected. Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

For Latest angular use this

//template

```
 <form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <select formControlName="testControl">
       <option **[ngValue]="null" disabled**>Please choose an option</option>
       <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.title">
       {{ option.title}}
       </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

//component

```
options = [{ id: 1, title: 'title 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'title 2' }];
testForm = new FormGroup({
   testControl: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="title" title="Please select title" [(ngModel)]="title">
        <option [selected]="true" >Title*</option>
        <option value="MD">MD</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
```

I simple added this [selected]="true" attribute its worked fine.